# Integral on discrete data points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numeric, numerical-integration

I need to calculate the integral of a function on some discrete data points in Matlab. I have the absolute coordinate of each point:
x=[1,2.65,3.25,3.33,15.65]
y=[10,31,15,-6,1]
I was trying to use `trapz(x,y)` function but there x must be the spacing between data points, not the x coordinate of data points.

What is the easiest way to calculate such an integration?

Answer (score 0):

With `integral` you can specify way points as option in 1D. With `integral2` for 2D integration, it seems you cannot.

It also seems you have a 2D rectangular grid of integration points?

In that case just calculate weights according to the mean interval lengths (via `diff`) and then sum up. Since your integration grid is fixed, the precision of the numerical integration will anyway not be controllable and will depend on the function you'll integrate.

```
% get grid
x = [1, 3, 7, 15]';
y = [3, 6, 8];
[xi, yi] = ndgrid(x, y);

% get weights
h = diff(x, [], 1);
wx = ([h; 1] + [1; h]) / 2;
h = diff(y, [], 2);
wy = ([h, 1] + [1, h]) / 2;
w = wx * wy;

% calculate function
f = func(xi, yi);

% integration is weighted summation
int = sum(f(:) .* w(:));
```

Borders will have to be treated carefully. Also, your list of coordinates needs to be sorted.